# NSSharingService creates "frozen" modal window for CKShare

Tags: cloudkit, appkit

I'm trying to present info about a `CKShare` to a user. You can do this as follows:

```
let container: CKContainer = /* existing CKContainer */
let share: CKShare = /* existing CKShare */

let item = NSItemProvider()
item.registerCloudKitShare(share, container: container)

let sharingService = NSSharingService(named: .cloudSharing)
sharingService.perform(withItems: [item])
```

This correctly opens the window:

[image: ckshare-window]

However, I cannot click anything in the window, and after closing the window I cannot click anything in my app.

EDIT: after further investigation, I realized I can navigate the UI using the keyboard. However, it is still quite buggy (triggering Done or pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> dismisses the view controller but doesn't close the window, and throws an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`)

The stack trace (below) shows that the main thread is waiting for events in the modal event loop:

```html
#0  0x00007fff7de8b20a in mach_msg_trap ()
#1  0x00007fff7de8a724 in mach_msg ()
#2  0x00007fff55ef9785 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()
#3  0x00007fff55ef8ad7 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#4  0x00007fff55ef8153 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#5  0x00007fff551e2d96 in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode ()
#6  0x00007fff551e2b06 in ReceiveNextEventCommon ()
#7  0x00007fff551e2884 in _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter ()
#8  0x00007fff53493a73 in _DPSNextEvent ()
#9  0x00007fff53c29e34 in -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] ()
#10 0x00007fff536c5e7b in -[NSApplication _doModalLoop:peek:] ()
#11 0x00007fff538aac9f in __35-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#12 0x00007fff538aac4c in __35-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]_block_invoke ()
#13 0x00007fff53d59219 in _NSTryRunModal ()
#14 0x00007fff536c3911 in -[NSApplication runModalForWindow:] ()
#15 0x00007fff53fc4289 in __87-[_NSCloudSharingService _showParticipantListServiceInSheetAttachedToWindow:withItems:]_block_invoke ()
#16 0x00007fff7a9ef0f4 in -[NSRemoteView _completeAdvanceToRunPhase:withError:] ()
#17 0x00007fff7a9d3c69 in __35-[NSRemoteView _advanceToRunPhase:]_block_invoke.1071 ()
#18 0x00007fff55ef5bec in __invoking___ ()
#19 0x00007fff55ef5ac0 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#20 0x00007fff7aa172d2 in withHintInProgress ()
#21 0x00007fff7a98e792 in __deferNSXPCInvocationOntoMainThread_block_invoke ()
#22 0x00007fff7aa1cb9d in __wrapBlockWithVoucher_block_invoke ()
#23 0x00007fff7a98e36f in __deferBlockOntoMainThread_block_invoke_2 ()
#24 0x00007fff55f1687c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#25 0x00007fff55ef9253 in __CFRunLoopDoBlocks ()
#26 0x00007fff55ef9018 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#27 0x00007fff55ef8153 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#28 0x00007fff7aa1690e in __invokeRunLoopInModeForDuration_block_invoke_2 ()
#29 0x00007fff7aa16862 in invokeRunLoopInModeForDuration ()
#30 0x00007fff7a9f371b in __29-[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait:]_block_invoke_2 ()
#31 0x00007fff7a9f3641 in __29-[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait:]_block_invoke ()
#32 0x00007fff7a9f2aac in +[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore _observe:whilePerforming:] ()
#33 0x00007fff7a9f332e in -[NSCFRunLoopSemaphore wait:] ()
#34 0x00007fff7a9cb9ed in -[NSRemoteViewSemaphore wait:] ()
#35 0x00007fff7a9d43db in -[NSRemoteView _waitOnSemaphore:] ()
#36 0x00007fff7a9e95a6 in -[NSRemoteView _didSetOriginOrSize:] ()
#37 0x00007fff7a9e9a7f in -[NSRemoteView setFrameSize:] ()
#38 0x00007fff7aa146e9 in withImplicitAnimation ()
#39 0x00007fff7a9e0184 in -[NSRemoteView _serviceRequestsResize:completion:] ()
#40 0x00007fff7a9e093e in -[NSRemoteView _serviceRequestsResize:animate:transaction:completion:] ()
#41 0x00007fff7a993ec4 in -[NSRemoteViewMarshal serviceRequestsResize:animate:transaction:completion:] ()
#42 0x00007fff55ef5bec in __invoking___ ()
#43 0x00007fff55ef5ac0 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#44 0x00007fff7aa172d2 in withHintInProgress ()
#45 0x00007fff7a98e83e in __deferNSXPCInvocationOntoMainThread_block_invoke ()
#46 0x00007fff7aa1cb9d in __wrapBlockWithVoucher_block_invoke ()
#47 0x00007fff7a98e36f in __deferBlockOntoMainThread_block_invoke_2 ()
#48 0x00007fff55f1687c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#49 0x00007fff55ef9253 in __CFRunLoopDoBlocks ()
#50 0x00007fff55ef9018 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#51 0x00007fff55ef8153 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#52 0x00007fff551e2d96 in RunCurrentEventLoopInMode ()
#53 0x00007fff551e2b06 in ReceiveNextEventCommon ()
#54 0x00007fff551e2884 in _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter ()
#55 0x00007fff53493a73 in _DPSNextEvent ()
#56 0x00007fff53c29e34 in -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] ()
#57 0x00007fff53488885 in -[NSApplication run] ()
#58 0x00007fff53457a72 in NSApplicationMain ()
#59 0x000000010000d831 in main() at main.swift:25
#60 0x000000010000d324 in main at main.swift:28
#61 0x00007fff7dd44015 in start ()
#62 0x00007fff7dd44015 in start ()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Is your code above being executed on the main thread?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem in an Objective-C project and found I needed to use the NSSharingServiceDelegate method to return the source Window.

```
- (NSWindow *)sharingService:(NSSharingService *)sharingService sourceWindowForShareItems:(NSArray *)items sharingContentScope:(NSSharingContentScope *)sharingContentScope{

    return self.view.window;

}
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssharingservicedelegate/1402679-sharingservice

`[NSSharingService performWithItems:NSArrayOfItems];` on the main thread would then present a sheet that functions correctly.

If from the owners `privateCloudDatabase` you would be presented all participants with sharing options, and like your screenshot, reduced participant options including ‘Remove Me’ if the shared record resides in the `sharedCloudDatabase`.